# Php sessions login - nothing happens, why?

Tags: php, mysql, session, authentication

I have a MySQL database with a user called admin (and password admin). I am using this to test my configuration. When I click login, nothing happens. Can anyone see if I've done something wrong?

Here is my logon form:

```
    <form action="loginProcess.php" method="POST">
    Username: <input type='text' name='username'></br>

    <!-- input type password makes the password hidden as it is typed -->
    &nbsp;Password: <input type='password' name='password'></br>


    <input type='submit' value='Login'/>

    </form>
    </br>
    </br>
    <!-- Register New User -->
    <form action="register.php" method="POST"> </br>
    Not Registered?<input type='submit' value='Click Here To Register'/>

    </form>
```

This form takes you to this loginProcess.php file:

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
// Include database connection and select database UFPProducts
include "./shopdb/connection.php";

?>
<?php
    //
// (2) Collect data from form and save in variables
// real escape string to protect from SQLi attacks
$username=mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['username']));
$password=mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['password']));

// (3) Create query of the form below to search the user table
//   "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName='$username' AND  Password='$password'"

$query = "SELECT * FROM USERS where Username='$username' AND Password='$password'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error()); 

// (3) Run query through connection

// (4) Check result of query using code below

// if rows found set authenticated user to the user name entered 
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) { 
$_SESSION["authenticatedUser"] = $username;
// Relocate to the logged-in page
header("Location: ./login/loggedOn.php");
} 
else
// login failed redirect back to login page with error message
{
$_SESSION["message"] = "Could not connect as $username " ;
header("Location: login.php");
}
?>
```

And here is my connection.php file just incase anyone wants to see:

```
<?php 
//***  "die()" will exit the script and show an error if something goes wrong with the "connect" or "select" functions. 
//***  A "mysql_connect()" error usually means your connection specific details are wrong 
//***  A "mysql_select_db()" error usually means the database does not exist.

// Place db host name. Usually is "localhost" but sometimes a more direct string is needed
$db_host = "localhost";
// Place the username for the MySQL database here
$db_username = "root"; 
// Place the password for the MySQL database here
$db_pass = "";
// Place the name for the MySQL database here
$db_name = "UFPProducts";

$connect = mysql_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die("there is no database with that name");

// echo "<center>You are successfully connected to the Under5Pounds database.</center><br>";
?>
```

I'm not getting any error messages right now, it just doesn't do anything once I type in the username + password and click login.

Comment: What debugging have you done? have you looked at the data in the $_POST array to see it is there? Have you tried running your SQL queries manually in a MySQL prompt? Have you enabled all error messages in PHP and have you read your error log files?

Comment: I haven't really done any debugging just yet because I haven't got any error messages to go by. My SQL queries seem to work OK in a MySQL prompt.

Answer (score 0):

try this code in loginProcess.php

```
$username=$_POST['username'];
```

$password=$_POST['password'];

Comment: SELECT command denied to user ''@'localhost' for table 'users'


I've now got that error coming up. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure about your mysql rights? You're connecting with root without password. Try to create a new user and give all rights on table Users to him

Comment: I'm a bit confused now. My registration form works fine. But when the user tries to log in, they get that error.

I'm not sure how to give all rights to every user automatically so they can then logon after registering

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove 
    ob_start(); 
from the first line of loginProcess.php file, it has nothing to do there (unless tell me the good reason) and it blocks data to be sent to the browser

Comment: I removed ob_start(); - Someone on StackOverflow told me to use it yesterday. 

I've removed it and changed the code in loginProcess.php to:


$username=$_POST['username'];

$password=$_POST['password'];

as suggested above, but still, nothing happens